# Launch only the video camera ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, camera

How can I only have a rec button, and nothing more?

Comment: What does your code look like? How does it not give you the results you expected? What results would you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your UIImagePickerController set mediaTypes to be an array with just kUTTypeMovie in it:

```
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```